# Dual Maass form for level=N in GL(2)

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, modular-forms, analytic-number-theory

Let $\Gamma=\Gamma_o(N)$ be the congruence subgroup.
Let $f\in C^\infty(\Gamma\backslash GL(2,R)/SO(2,R)R^*)$ be a Maass form. How shall we define its dual(contragredient) Maass form $f'$?

If $\Gamma=SL(2,Z)$, it is known that the dual Maass form should be $f'(z)=f(\omega (z^t)^{-1}\omega^{-1})$, where $$\omega=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

If $f(z)$ is a Maass form of weight zero and level $N$ on the upper half-plane, then the dual form is $f\left(\frac{-1}{Nz}\right)$. One can transfer this statement to $GL(2,R)$ using Iwasawa coordinates.